# Reason for conversion to Dalvik error 1

Tags: android, dalvik

After upgrading my Android SDK, Eclipse, and Eclipse ADT versions (a long and painful process), export fails with the well-known *Conversion to dalvik format failed with error 1* popup message. I have tried many of the suggested solutions posted on the Internet to no avail. A truly amazing number of developers seem to encounter this problem, but tracking down the cause remains obscure in many cases.

I am using Android SDK tools version 19, Eclipse ADT version 18. I am not using Proguard. My application relies on a single Library project. The other jar files needed by my application reside in the project's libs/ directory; I have NOT added them explicitly as libraries in the Java build path, per this [Dealing With Dependencies](http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects) article.

**What exactly does "error 1" mean - where are the error codes documented?**

Eclipse does not show any messages that indicate why "error 1" occurred - I don't see any messages in the console (e.g. no "IllegalArgumentException: already added"), and nothing obvious in the "Problems" panel. Other than the "Conversion to dalvik failed" popup, the only other error indicator I see is in my workspace .metadata/.log file:

```
!SUBENTRY 1 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-05-30 17:20:49.179
!MESSAGE Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
!STACK 0
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexException: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:713)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ExportHelper.exportReleaseApk(ExportHelper.java:251)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.doExport(ExportWizard.java:295)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard.access$0(ExportWizard.java:232)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.wizards.export.ExportWizard$1.run(ExportWizard.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Can anyone offer more guidance please?

Comment: add the libraries to ur build path

Comment: Sherif, that approach seems counter to the changes introduced at r17 of the ADT as documented at http://tools.android.com/recent/dealingwithdependenciesinandroidprojects, and has other problems for my project. Do Eclipse and/or the underlying SDK tools log more details somewhere during the export process?

Comment: Diagnostic information about this error is printed to the Eclipse console when the application is "Run as Android Application", i.e. using the device emulator. I had been getting the error when trying to export; in this case diagnostic information is not printed.

Comment: i do not know why! but sometimes i get output in the console and sometimes not.